# Access SQL - consolidated SUM

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of several hundred thousand similar records and I am trying to consolidate multiple similar records into a more concise table. The SQL query I have used below doesn't give me accurate results when compared with the original table, but I am not sure why.

The table is intended to pull all fields from the original table but consolidate each record in to a single unique record with a sum of the count, so the sum of count should correspond exactly with the sum from the original table.

```
SELECT Date_mday, date_month, date_year, [Message#EventID], aaRequestType, 
[Message#SecurityParameters#AccountNumber] , 
[Message#SecurityParameters#LogonUserID] , 
InstitutionPOBoxCountry, 
[Message#SecurityParameters#RoleData] , 
Sum(Count) AS SumOfCount
FROM TempImport
GROUP BY Date_mday, date_month, date_year, [Message#EventID], aaRequestType, [Message#SecurityParameters#AccountNumber], [Message#SecurityParameters#LogonUserID], InstitutionPOBoxCountry, [Message#SecurityParameters#RoleData], Count;
```

I'm certain that this is straightforward to solve but I have tried a few different approaches and am pretty stumped.

My original table looks like this:

```
 date_mday | date_month | date_year | Message#EventID | aaRequestType | Message#SecurityParameters#AccountNumber | Message#SecurityParameters#LogonUserID | InstitutionPOBoxCountry | Message#SecurityParameters#RoleData | count 
-----------|------------|-----------|-----------------|---------------|------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------------------------|-------
 1         | Jan        | 2017      | XML-INPUT       | GetData       | A1234                                    | AAA1234                                | GB                      | VALIDATE                            | 1     
 1         | Jan        | 2017      | XML-INPUT       | GetData       | A1234                                    | AAA1234                                | GB                      | VALIDATE                            | 1     
 1         | Jan        | 2017      | XML-INPUT       | GetData       | A1234                                    | AAA1234                                | GB                      | VALIDATE                            | 1     
 1         | Jan        | 2017      | XML-INPUT       | GetData       | A1234                                    | AAA1234                                | GB                      | VALIDATE                            | 1
```

And the consolidated table would have a single line, but with the final column (SumOfCount) as 4.

Comment: Please provide table structure, sample data, desired results and actual results. You can use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to post table data in StackOverflow.

Comment: You're aggregating on the field `Count`, so you probably don't want that field to be in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

`count` is the field you are aggregating.  If you include it in the `GROUP BY`, you will get a separate row for each `count` value.

Because you want to sum the values:

```
SELECT Date_mday, date_month, date_year, [Message#EventID], aaRequestType, 
       [Message#SecurityParameters#AccountNumber],[Message#SecurityParameters#LogonUserID] , 
       InstitutionPOBoxCountry, [Message#SecurityParameters#RoleData] , 
       Sum(Count) AS SumOfCount
FROM TempImport
GROUP BY Date_mday, date_month, date_year, [Message#EventID], aaRequestType, [Message#SecurityParameters#AccountNumber], 
         [Message#SecurityParameters#LogonUserID], InstitutionPOBoxCountry, [Message#SecurityParameters#RoleData];
```

Your `GROUP BY` should only contain columns that are not part of aggregation functions.

Comment: It seems so obvious when you put it that way! I will check shortly to see if that works. Thanks a lot.